# What's the English expression that means 感叹词："坏了"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, word-requests, phrase, equivalent-phrase

In Chinese there is a 感叹词："坏了", means something went unexpected wrong. Example:

> 坏了，下雨了
>   坏了，手机忘带了
>   坏了，迟到了

What are the common English expressions that can express that "astonishing strike"?

**UPDATE:** Thanks everyone for your answer. To foster participation, I'll make my pick a week later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

- "Shoot!"

  - "Shoot; it's raining."
  - "Shoot; I forgot to bring my phone."
  - "Shoot; I'm late."
- "Darn."

  - "Darn, it's raining."
  - "Darn! I forgot to bring my phone."
  - "Darn; I'm late."
- "Oh no."

  - "Oh no, it's raining."
  - "Oh no. I forgot to bring my phone."
  - "Oh no; I'm late."

To emphasize that "astonishing strike," perhaps something like

> "Shoot, shoot, shoot! Darn it! I forgot to bring my phone!"
>
> "坏了，坏了！忘带手机了！"

Comment: Thanks. I've also found *"Oh snap!"*, but don't know how widely it is used. Also, I've heard saying *"Oh bummer!"* (hope I've picked the correct word).

Answer (score 2):

I am native speaker of Chinese. I guess "oh, no", "gosh", or "too bad" are OK.

Answer (score 1):

"Damn!"

"Hell!"

"Crap!"

These are pretty colloquial.